# Using wininet to exchange data with server

Tags: c++, post, get, wininet

I'm using WinInet to download file from web. But not I need the following:

1. Post id to the script;
2. Download the file bound to this id;

I know how to download some file:

```
hConnection = InternetConnect(hInet, "server.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnection, _T("GET"), "script.php", NULL, NULL, 
    0, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);
...
while (1)
{
   InternetReadFile(hRequest, (BYTE*)pBuffer, nBytesToRead, &dwBytesReturned);
   if (dwBytesReturned == 0)
    break;
}
```

But what should I do to POST some id, wait for the answer and download file? Is it possible with WinInet or should I use WinSock?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do http POST (as PUT and DELETE btw) using WinInet.

Take a look for example here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/wininet_wrapper_part1.aspx